# STS Authentication - MVC Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, wif

I have two servers: STS and Web.  On the STS server, I call:

```
FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, false);
```

The next line, I check:

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

This is set to TRUE.  Then I redirect back to my Web server and in the controller I hit, I check:

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

This is set to FALSE.

```
What could cause this?
```

UPDATE: I also just tried moving the STS web site to the Web server. I get the same error/issue

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that our DEV server works just fine.  The configuration there is identical (except for the server name and cert thumbprints).  The only thing different between these two servers is that one (DEV) is using a self-signed cert and is inside our firewall.  The other (QA) is using an official (thawte) cert and is ourside our firewall.  This cert's common name does not match the server name (so it can be shared in our farm).  So when we access the site, we do so using https://[commonname].com/web as opposed to https://[servername]/web.  I tried the latter approach (I get cert errors that there is a name mismatch) but still have the same result.

Also, I can access the STS site directly and login fine there.

Comment: I need your web application <microsoft.identity> section to get any idea about what might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET authentication is based on cookie by default. Cookie lives inside web domain.
So if you have two servers installed like this:

1. http://www.web.com
2. http://www.sts.com

WEB server cannot read cookie set by STS

There are two possible solutions:

1. Implement both servers as sub-domains
2. Store authentication ticket in URL instead of cookie

For option 1
Move servers as follows:

1. http://www.web.yourdomain.com
2. http://www.sts.yourdomain.com

Update web.config to scope cookie to yourdomain.com:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms domain=".yourdomain.com"/>
</authentication>
```

For storing ticket in url check this article - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2796/Cookieless-ASP-NET-forms-authentication

**Update: Seems that I did not get that STS stands for Security Token Service. My answer is not relevant. :(**

Answer (score 0):

While redirecting from your `STS` server you will have to redirect using the `AutoPost`form which will submit the `token` to the `Relying party`.

And when `Relying party` will receive the token it will create the cookie against that user.

So next time whnen you will check `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` at Relying party it will return you `True`.

Go throung the following link to know more,

http://chris.59north.com/post/2013/03/27/Claims-based-identities-in-ASPNET-MVC-45-using-the-standard-ASPNET-providers.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue when moving the RP to a different server.  It turns out that we needed to go into the application pool -> advanced settings -> Set 'Load User Profile' = true.

After that, everything worked as it should on the new server and User.Identity.IsAuthenticated was returning 'true' after it came back from the STS.